# Обрабатывать любой одинарный и двойной клик

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо после запуска приложения обрабатывать любые двойные и одинарные клики мыши, даже при свёрнутом в трей приложении, но чтобы само действие при этом выполнялось. Например, запуск других программ, открытие файлов и переход по ссылкам. Это вообще реально сделать на джаве?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит конечно от конкретной задачи, но исходя из вашего описания прямого решения нет. В java мало возможностей для непосредственного контроля за функциями ОС, за кроссплатформенность приходится платить.
Думаю решить ваш вопрос можно только через Java Native Interface (JNI). То есть имплементация слушателя на C который будет слушать нажатия клавиш, как это сделать, видимо искать на MSDN(если Windows) или где-то еще. Если Linux то думаю найти будет проще. Ну а интеграция с Java не сложная.

Немного поиска и даже есть готовые библиотеки на Git - https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, на чистой java прямого решения нет. Можно воспользоваться библиотеками, использующими jni, например эта https://github.com/kristian/system-hook. 
Как вариант, можно поэкспериментировать с классом java.awt.PointerInfo. Через него можно получить актуальные координаты мыши, но без обработки событий.

```
    PointerInfo inf = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point p = inf.getLocation();
    System.out.println(p.x + ":" + p.y);
```